# how to use try/catch in streamBuilder?

Tags: flutter, dart, try-catch, stream-builder

I want to do sign-in page and when I use streamBuilder<user?> and want to cover all cases (if the account exists or not) the compiler notes me there is an error inside the builder and you have to make it Async. when I tried to make it like what the compiler say also show another compilation error

my code is:

```dart
 ElevatedButton(
  onPressed: logIn,
  child: StreamBuilder<User?>(
    stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      try {
        print('inside bulder method');
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          print('have account');
          return home();
        }
      } catch (e) {
        print("dont have acc");
        return login();
      }
      //checkIn(context, snapshot);
    },
  ),
)
```

I try to make it as a method but also have the same error

I want to solve it to display a message to the user (there is something error)

Comment: You might want to switch to a RiverPod StreamProvider, which can capture an error as part of its AsyncValue interface.

Answer (score 0):

You will get error from `snapshot.hasError`.

```dart
ElevatedButton(
  onPressed: logIn,
  child: StreamBuilder<User?>(
    stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.hasError) {

      } else if (snapshot.connectionState ==
          ConnectionState.waiting) {

      } else if (snapshot.hasData) {

      }else {
        
      }
    },
  ),
)
```

More on [flutter.dev](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StreamBuilder-class.html)